# How to run html with JS scripts on WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to run the below html code with JS scripts into webview.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//static.apester.com/js/sdk/v1.1/apester-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <body>
         <interaction id="56fda67582287b5830c4ec8f"></interaction>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code runs on [Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed)

I have added the **INTERNET permission to the manifest**

**XML code (nothing new):**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="bet.abpla.webviewdemo02.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Identifier = "56fda67582287b5830c4ec8f";
    String Mime = "text/html";
    String Encoding = "UTF-8";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getHTMLData(Identifier), Mime, Encoding, null);
    }

    private String getHTMLData(String ApesterId) {

        return "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                "<html>" +
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//static.apester.com/js/sdk/v1.1/apester-sdk.min.js\"></script>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<interaction id=\"" + ApesterId + "\"></interaction>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</html>";
    }

}
```

Pasting the above HTML code on [Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed) will display the intended result.

Unfortunately in android, it's displaying nothing (simply a blank white screen with the default actionbar without the Hello World text). Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

change the last line of your code to:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", getHTMLData(Identifier), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```